# How to convert a JSON object to Javascript array filtered by key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I'm returning a JSON object from an Ajax request which outputs the following keys and values:

```
[{"App_Name":"Maccy D's","ID":2017},{"App_Name":"B King","ID":2011}]
```

I need to convert this object to a Javascript array where each `App_Name` and `ID` value is concatenated as one string in the array. So for example:

```
['Maccy D's 2017', 'B King 2011'] // etc...
```

What I have tried is calling

```
var assetsArray = JSON.parse(assetJSON);
```

but when I bind the `assetsArray` to a list it shows `[object Object]` for each menu item. Instead of the intended `App_Name` + `ID` concatenation:

[image]

How can I convert a JSON object to Javascript array filtered by key?

This is how I bind the JSON returned to the menu list:

Ajax request:

```
    //call an Ajax GET for the asset name data
    $.ajax({
        url: asset_list_request_url,
        cache: false,
        success: function(assetJSON){
            bindAssetNamesMenu(assetJSON);
        }
    });
```

Mapping function:

```
    function bindAssetNamesMenu(assetJSON)
    {

        var assetsArray = JSON.parse(assetJSON);

        $.each(assetsArray, function(i)
        {
            var li = $('<li/>')
            .addClass('ui-menu-item')
            .attr('role', 'menuitem')
            .appendTo(assetMenu);


            var a = $('<a>')
                 .addClass('ui-all')
                 .appendTo(li);

            var input = $('<input/>')
                  .addClass('ui-all')
                  .attr('type', 'checkbox')
                  .appendTo(a);


            var span = $('<span>')
                  .text(assetsArray[i])
                  .appendTo(a);


        });

    }
```

Comment: Your `object` already is an `array`. So what would you like to do?!

Comment: Use `assetsArray[i].App_Name` instead of `assetsArray[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you don't need `var assetsArray = JSON.parse(assetJSON);`
2. keep your names straight, not `assetJSON` and `assetArray`
3. you have to access the property of the array index, like `assetJSON[i].App_Name`

Then your code is working fine!

```js
var data = [{
  "App_Name": "Maccy D's",
  "ID": 2017
}, {
  "App_Name": "B King",
  "ID": 2011
}];

var assetMenu = $("ul");
bindAssetNamesMenu(data);

function bindAssetNamesMenu(assetJSON) {
  $.each(assetJSON, function(i) {
    var li = $('<li/>')
      .addClass('ui-menu-item')
      .attr('role', 'menuitem')
      .appendTo(assetMenu);

    var a = $('<a>')
      .addClass('ui-all')
      .appendTo(li);

    var input = $('<input/>')
      .addClass('ui-all')
      .attr('type', 'checkbox')
      .appendTo(a);

    var span = $('<span>')
      .text(assetJSON[i].ID + " - " + assetJSON[i].App_Name)
      .appendTo(a);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map()` to get the array of objects in to an array of the format you require:

```js
var data = [{"App_Name":"Maccy D's","ID":2017},{"App_Name":"B King","ID":2011}]
var arr = data.map(function(obj) {
    return obj.App_Name + ' ' + obj.ID;
})

console.log(arr);
```

Alternatively, you could just work with the array of objects as it is, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: asset_list_request_url,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: bindAssetNamesMenu
});

function bindAssetNamesMenu(arr) {
    $.each(arr, function() {
        var $li = $('<li/>').addClass('ui-menu-item').attr('role', 'menuitem').appendTo(assetMenu);
        var $a = $('<a>').addClass('ui-all').appendTo($li);
        var $input = $('<input/>').addClass('ui-all').attr('type', 'checkbox').appendTo($a);
        var $span = $('<span>').text(this.App_Name + ' ' + this.ID).appendTo($a);
    });
}
```

Comment: This works and also as Maxx suggested the obvious solution is to just set the text like `.text(assetsArray[i].App_Name + assetsArray[i].ID)` I was confused and the object is already an array.

Comment: That would work too. I assumed you needed the array formatted that way for use elsewhere in your code. If not, you can just loop through the objects in your original array.

Comment: @eisbehr I assumed the OP needed the data in that format for use elsewhere in his code. This appears not to be the case, so I updated my answer with an alternate solution

Comment: Yes, just saw it. I think this is better now. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to code in the imperative style then you can always use `for of` loop such as;

```js
var  data = [{"App_Name":"Maccy D's","ID":2017},{"App_Name":"B King","ID":2011}],
    datar = [];
for (var object of data) datar.push(object.App_Name + " " + object.ID);
console.log(datar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using `jQuery.each` function to loop through the json and concatenate the required strings using either `concat` property *(javascript)* or directly use **+**(concatenation operator)

```
var json = [{"App_Name":"Maccy D's","ID":2017},{"App_Name":"B King","ID":2011}];
var arr = [];
jQuery.each(json,function(){
    arr.push(this.App_Name.concat(this.ID))
});

console.log(arr); // This will display ["Maccy D's 2017", "B King 2011"]
```